# IIlustrate the relationship between the columns of the matrix in one figure using subplot()

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, subplot

I have a matrix of 10 columns and 20000 rows.

I need to build a plot to illustrate the relationship between the dimensions (columns) in one figure using subplot(). So like to compare 1st column to 1, 2, 3..10, 2 to 1st, 2, 3, 4, ...10th etc. 
Should this be nested for loop? 
I don't know where to start and isn't its easier to use plotmatrix(data,data) for example?

thank you for any advice

```
l

oad('data.mat')  %% loads matrix called data
 x = data; %% to make it faster 
counter = 1; %%i ndex to make subplot function plot to the next row later on (fill further rows, beyond 1st one )
for c = 1:10; %% condition to make matrix 10 by 10
for i=1:10; %% condition to make matrix 10 by 10
    subplot(10,10,counter); %% 10 by 10 grid for plots
plot (x( : ,i),x( : ,c)); %% actual plot command that uses columns of the matrix
counter = counter+1; %% 
end 
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? You want 10 plots with one of the variables on the x-axis in each case against all of the other variables? Or you want 10*10=100 plots, one for each pair (with repeats)? What's wrong with the code you've provided?

Comment: Wolfie, thank you very much for your reply. I guess its ok, I just don't know why we have been asked to use subplot instead plotmatrix here

Comment: The only one who can answer that for sure is whoever asked you to use `subplot`!